# Biggest rectangle inside a random geometric shape

Tags: integration, geometry, algorithms, area, monte-carlo

I'm looking for the most efficient algorithm to find the rectangle with the greatest area inside a  random geometric shape. The rectangle can be also rotated of course. I am sure that there  exists a method like Monte Carlo for the integration.

Comment: How is your shape given? Do you require optimality, or are approximations and/or probabilistic results acceptable as well?

Comment: I need this algorithm to calculate a fitness function, for an optimization problem. I already use Monte Carlo for calculating area. I prefer fast computing rather then optimality. The shape varies in function of 2 parameters but I would like a generic method, not shape dependent.

Comment: That still doesn't tell me how your shape is described. Is it a polygon defined by a sequence of corners? Or a convex polygon defined by a bunch of intersecting half spaces? Is it a Bézier curve? Some other parametric curve? Smooth boundary? Or piecewise smooth? Analytic? “random geometric shape” is *way* too generic when talking about algorithms.

Comment: Well you are right. It is continuous, without holes inside. Generically it is piecewise smooth. It is a workspace of a kinematic chain. I am sorry but for Monte Carlo I check the singularity for calculating area. I was wondering if there is something easy like this.